# MySQL Select data separated strings

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to select a record using the LIKE function. However, it does not show results if there are characters in between. I want it to select data that contains those strings. For example:

```
 $value = "Mark Anthony";
 $qry ="SELECT * FROM students WHERE name LIKE '%$value%'";
```

returns these results:

```
 John Mark Anthony
 Mark Anthony Philipps
```

but I also want to have results like these

```
 Mark James Anthony
 Mark Gabriel Anthony Fernandez
 Marko Julian Anthonyo
```

Any ideas?
UPDATE: 'Mark' must be before 'Anthony'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

last try:

```
$value = "Mark Anthony";
$value = str_replace(" ","%",$value);
$qry ="SELECT * FROM students WHERE name LIKE '%$value%'";
```

not tested!

Comment: Updated my question. Do you think it will also include results like this? Marko Julian Anthonyo?

Comment: Just tested it. No results were found. xD

Comment: Just a blank page. Not even errors. But your new answer works great! Why didn't I think of str_replace xD Thanks man!

Comment: nice to hear. as you see my first answer was a bit overloaded too ;-)

Answer (score 6):

I think Full TEXT works

But Full-text searches are supported for `MyISAM` tables only

```
SELECT * FROM students 
  WHERE MATCH (name)
   AGAINST ('Mark Anthony' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

**UPDATE:-** As per question update OP need to search `Marko` as well, then you can get like this:-

```
SELECT * FROM students 
WHERE
(
    name LIKE '%Mark%'
    OR name LIKE '%Anthony%'
)
```

Comment: It's okay, I am using PHPmyadmin anyway. Will try this out.

Comment: Yes try it, I think in your case FULL TEXT is best

Comment: Updated my question. Will results like these appear? Marko Julian Anthonyo

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer :) Although I have already chosen an answer. Will upvote instead. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could split the value string into two parts. Like so:

```
WHERE name LIKE '%Mark%' AND name LIKE '%Anthony%'
```

Comment: Hi there, I haven't updated the question but Mark has to be before Anthony. With your suggestion I think it will include results with Anthony before Mark. :)

Comment: Yeah thats a possibility with my query. '%Mark%Anthony%' should do the trick tho.. @Elmer

Comment: Updated my question. Will results like these appear?
Marko Julian Anthonyo

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution -

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column REGEXP '(Mark).+(Anthony)';
```

Comment: Haven't tried this yet but was wondering if there was a solution that wouldn't be fixed to Mark Anthony only :) Like if I just want to look for 'Mark'.

Comment: Why haven't you tried this? Regex function sometimes can help.

Answer (score 0):

The proplem is, you say "bring all results which contains Mark Anthony" so it does. You should  set it like

```
$value = "Mark%Anthony";
```